# Prototype: apply vs call, new vs create

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I have a constructor function which I want to use as prototype for another constructor. both receive arguments:

```
function Proto(arg) {}

function Sub(arg) {}
```

What's a better way to pass the argument from `Sub` constructor to `Proto` constructor:

`Proto.apply(this, arg);`

`Proto.call(this, arg);` *(pun unintended...)*

Second, when I want to actually set the prototype, what is the difference between:

`Sub.prototype = Object.create( Proto );`

`Sub.prototype = new Proto();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `.call` and `.apply` is that `.call` takes its arguments as separate arguments for the function, while `.apply` takes the arguments as a single array. For example:

```
function myFunction(x, y) {
    var z;
    // Do something
    return z;
}

var context = {};

// The following function calls are equivalent:
var fx = myFunction.call(context, 5, 'h');
var fy = myFunction.apply(context, [5, 'h']);
```

In cases where you don't know the length of the argument list at compile time, you have to use `.apply`. But in this case you don't need to do that, and you can use the slightly simpler syntax of `.call`. If you were to do it with `.apply`, it would be `Proto.apply(this, [arg]);`.

As for `Object.create` versus `new`: Again, you've got the expression wrong, it should be `Sub.prototype = Object.create(Proto.prototype);`. I don't normally use `Object.create`, but as far as I can tell the only difference is the value of `Sub.prototype.constructor`. It probably doesn't matter much either way. However, the `new` way is more common and accepts arguments. (You can also give another argument to `Object.create`, but it works differently.)